# Does someone on a Fixed Remuneration Salary submit hours?

Tags: salary, contracts, employer-relations, australia

I noticed in my contract that I'm under a "Fixed Remuneration Package" for a certain amount per year, payable every two weeks. For this example let's assume I'm making 100k (I wish) per year so the math is nice and clean.

I'd assume that each pay packet I'd receive in the order of $4,166 (100000/24).

However my employer is having me submit time sheets and due to lunch breaks etc I'm often a few hours short of making that amount (2 or 3). It's small amounts but it'll add up to thousands lost at the end of the year.

My understanding is that on a Fixed Remuneration I should be paid regardless of these minor unworked hours and of additional hours. For reference I am in Australia but I assume the workplace law would be similar elsewhere.

Should I bring this to their attention? Was my understanding of this wrong?

I feel like I'm being paid as an hourly contractor rather than a full time employee.

Thanks!

Comment: The use of time sheets can be for different reasons. Do note that in my contract there is a minimum number of hours (40) to be performed each week but no maximum. If you are not working this set amount of hours then your employer is not getting what he is paying for.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks. On my contract when I was being inducted the "hours of work" was left blank, because at the time I was told "We're very flexible", but I've subsequently been told the normal amount of hours per pay period is around 86.67.

Comment: I would say to go along with what the others are doing as you don't want to be an outlier in those cases. If people are averaging 43 hours a week and you are averaging 37 it might show a bit.

Comment: We prefer questions that have practical answers here. What are you trying to do or learn? Your HR department should be able to explain how you're paid and what's expected of you with regards to hours. That's different in every country and sometimes different across industries or companies.

Answer (score 2):

Your hours shouldn't impact on your pay. However they may impact on your review.

Another reason that some ask for timesheets depends on the work you do, so for instance I have an engineer who works 8 hours a day, but I need to calculate how much of that I can bill to clients and how much was used on internal work, or in this chaps case, surfing the internet.

Comment: Thanks! I only do work for their in-house products, but I have a feeling the hours are for tax rebate purposes. I'll mention that I've noticed something inconsistent between my contract and pay and request they look into it.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia, fixed remuneration positions are typically paid to do a particular job. This job would be expected to take approximately some number of hours per week. The pay and hours are only loosely related. The pay is for the job, not the hours, however, to do the job properly you would likely be expected to work some minimum number of hours. In these sorts of positions, it is normally expected that you would in reality work over the minimum number of hours by some small margin without receiving additional pay. Significant and/or consistent overworking might indicate that you are inefficient as a worker or that you are overloaded with work. Typically, it would not be considered acceptable to work under the minimum number of hours. Some workplaces are flexible and will allow you to work under some weeks and over during other weeks as long as the total over some longer time frame works out.

It's not uncommon for people in salaried positions to complete timesheets. This is one way for the organisation to measure who is being overworked etc.

Your manager and/or HR department should be able to advise you on the specifics for your particular workplace.